# OpenLayers Cluster Recalculate

Tags: javascript, openlayers

So, I have a number of items clustered in OpenLayers.

I'm using a strategy that clusters the items based on their attributes.

I change an item's attribute.

How do I get the clustering strategy to recalculate the cluster?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that this feature is not available in OpenLayers as of 2.11RC1. Therefore, I have implemented it as a shadow of the Cluster class myself. The code is also available as a patch in the [OpenLayers Trac](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/3384).

The code at the end of this answer can be dropped directly into a javascript file and will override the existing OpenLayers `OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster` class. It adds a method `recluster` which, when called, will cause the strategy to recalculate its clustering. Since we are altering the `Cluster` base class, any derived class should appropriately inherit the `recluster` method.

An example of how to use this would be:

```
var clustering=new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()
var vectorlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Vectorlayer', {
                                              strategies: [clustering]
});

//ADD_LOTS_OF_FEATURES_TO_VECTOR_LAYER

clustering.distance=value;
clustering.recluster();
```

The code for the replacement class is:

```
OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Strategy, {

    /**
     * APIProperty: distance
     * {Integer} Pixel distance between features that should be considered a
     *     single cluster.  Default is 20 pixels.
     */
    distance: 20,

    /**
     * APIProperty: threshold
     * {Integer} Optional threshold below which original features will be
     *     added to the layer instead of clusters.  For example, a threshold
     *     of 3 would mean that any time there are 2 or fewer features in
     *     a cluster, those features will be added directly to the layer instead
     *     of a cluster representing those features.  Default is null (which is
     *     equivalent to 1 - meaning that clusters may contain just one feature).
     */
    threshold: null,

    /**
     * Property: features
     * {Array(<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>)} Cached features.
     */
    features: null,

    /**
     * Property: clusters
     * {Array(<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>)} Calculated clusters.
     */
    clusters: null,

    /**
     * Property: clustering
     * {Boolean} The strategy is currently clustering features.
     */
    clustering: false,

    /**
     * Property: resolution
     * {Float} The resolution (map units per pixel) of the current cluster set.
     */
    resolution: null,

    /**
     * Constructor: OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster
     * Create a new clustering strategy.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * options - {Object} Optional object whose properties will be set on the
     *     instance.
     */

    /**
     * APIMethod: activate
     * Activate the strategy.  Register any listeners, do appropriate setup.
     * 
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} The strategy was successfully activated.
     */
    activate: function() {
        var activated = OpenLayers.Strategy.prototype.activate.call(this);
        if(activated) {
            this.layer.events.on({
                "beforefeaturesadded": this.cacheFeatures,
                "moveend": this.cluster,
                scope: this
            });
        }
        return activated;
    },

    /**
     * APIMethod: deactivate
     * Deactivate the strategy.  Unregister any listeners, do appropriate
     *     tear-down.
     * 
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} The strategy was successfully deactivated.
     */
    deactivate: function() {
        var deactivated = OpenLayers.Strategy.prototype.deactivate.call(this);
        if(deactivated) {
            this.clearCache();
            this.layer.events.un({
                "beforefeaturesadded": this.cacheFeatures,
                "moveend": this.cluster,
                scope: this
            });
        }
        return deactivated;
    },

    /**
     * Method: cacheFeatures
     * Cache features before they are added to the layer.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * event - {Object} The event that this was listening for.  This will come
     *     with a batch of features to be clustered.
     *     
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} False to stop features from being added to the layer.
     */
    cacheFeatures: function(event) {
        var propagate = true;
        if(!this.clustering) {
            this.clearCache();
            this.features = event.features;
            this.cluster();
            propagate = false;
        }
        return propagate;
    },

    /**
     * Method: clearCache
     * Clear out the cached features.
     */
    clearCache: function() {
        this.features = null;
    },

    /**
     * Method: cluster
     * Cluster features based on some threshold distance.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * event - {Object} The event received when cluster is called as a
     *     result of a moveend event.
     */
    cluster: function(event) {
        if((!event || event.zoomChanged || (event && event.recluster)) && this.features) {
            var resolution = this.layer.map.getResolution();
            if(resolution != this.resolution || !this.clustersExist() || (event && event.recluster)) {
                this.resolution = resolution;
                var clusters = [];
                var feature, clustered, cluster;
                for(var i=0; i<this.features.length; ++i) {
                    feature = this.features[i];
                    if(feature.geometry) {
                        clustered = false;
                        for(var j=clusters.length-1; j>=0; --j) {
                            cluster = clusters[j];
                            if(this.shouldCluster(cluster, feature)) {
                                this.addToCluster(cluster, feature);
                                clustered = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(!clustered) {
                            clusters.push(this.createCluster(this.features[i]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.layer.removeAllFeatures();
                if(clusters.length > 0) {
                    if(this.threshold > 1) {
                        var clone = clusters.slice();
                        clusters = [];
                        var candidate;
                        for(var i=0, len=clone.length; i<len; ++i) {
                            candidate = clone[i];
                            if(candidate.attributes.count < this.threshold) {
                                Array.prototype.push.apply(clusters, candidate.cluster);
                            } else {
                                clusters.push(candidate);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    this.clustering = true;
                    // A legitimate feature addition could occur during this
                    // addFeatures call.  For clustering to behave well, features
                    // should be removed from a layer before requesting a new batch.
                    this.layer.addFeatures(clusters);
                    this.clustering = false;
                }
                this.clusters = clusters;
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Method: recluster
     * User-callable function to recluster features
     * Useful for instances where a clustering attribute (distance, threshold, ...)
     *     has changed
     */
    recluster: function(){
        var event={"recluster":true};
        this.cluster(event);
    },

    /**
     * Method: clustersExist
     * Determine whether calculated clusters are already on the layer.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} The calculated clusters are already on the layer.
     */
    clustersExist: function() {
        var exist = false;
        if(this.clusters && this.clusters.length > 0 &&
           this.clusters.length == this.layer.features.length) {
            exist = true;
            for(var i=0; i<this.clusters.length; ++i) {
                if(this.clusters[i] != this.layer.features[i]) {
                    exist = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return exist;
    },

    /**
     * Method: shouldCluster
     * Determine whether to include a feature in a given cluster.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * cluster - {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>} A cluster.
     * feature - {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>} A feature.
     *
     * Returns:
     * {Boolean} The feature should be included in the cluster.
     */
    shouldCluster: function(cluster, feature) {
        var cc = cluster.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat();
        var fc = feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat();
        var distance = (
            Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow((cc.lon - fc.lon), 2) + Math.pow((cc.lat - fc.lat), 2)
            ) / this.resolution
        );
        return (distance <= this.distance);
    },

    /**
     * Method: addToCluster
     * Add a feature to a cluster.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * cluster - {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>} A cluster.
     * feature - {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>} A feature.
     */
    addToCluster: function(cluster, feature) {
        cluster.cluster.push(feature);
        cluster.attributes.count += 1;
    },

    /**
     * Method: createCluster
     * Given a feature, create a cluster.
     *
     * Parameters:
     * feature - {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>}
     *
     * Returns:
     * {<OpenLayers.Feature.Vector>} A cluster.
     */
    createCluster: function(feature) {
        var center = feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat();
        var cluster = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(center.lon, center.lat),
            {count: 1}
        );
        cluster.cluster = [feature];
        return cluster;
    },

    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster" 
});
```

Comment: Excellent, this was just what I needed! Couple of things... 1) You can add this to the core js (cluster.js) and then rebuild your own custom OpenLayers.js to avoid having to re-implement all of this. Or.. 2) You shold be able to add these methods to the class without having to re-code the whole class.

Comment: Good points, @Matt. My preferred method would be to just have it as part of OpenLayers. It's Ticket #3384, active since 2011-06-23. Maybe it will make it into v2.13... :-)

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster.cluster method recalculate only if it is a zoomechanged event or clusters object does not exist. remove the clusters object and call cluster on Cluster object.

```
var clustering=new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()
var vectorlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Vectorlayer', {
                                              strategies: [clustering]
});

//ADD_LOTS_OF_FEATURES_TO_VECTOR_LAYER

clustering.distance=value;
//cluster() recalculate only if it is a zoomechanged event or clusters object does not exist.
clustering.clusters = null; //remove cluster object so that it calculates again.
clustering.cluster();
```