# OpenLayers: How to refresh map after changing the vector layer

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers, I have a cluster strategy to limit how many features/points the user sees on the map. When the user is fully zoomed in however, I want to turn off the clustering strategy so that all features are shown. To do this I am catching the zoom event like this:

```
map.events.register("zoomend", this, function (e) {
    if (map.getZoom() === this.mapMaxZoom) {
        // Don't cluster at this level. No matter what.
        this.vector.strategies[0].threshold = 1000;
        console.log("setting the clustering strategy to 1000");
    }
});
```

This kinda works, but I don't see the new clustering applied - I have to zoom back out again to see the clustering change to a threshold of 1000 (and thus show all features). I need some way to force openlayers to refresh. I've tried calling map.redraw() but that doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in this post. [OpenLayers Cluster Recalculate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457437/openlayers-cluster-recalculate)

Basically, I need to set the cluster strategy, then "recluster". Works a treat.

Answer (score 15):

`vectorlayer.refresh({force:true});`
Try this.

Comment: I found that in openlayers 3 you need to call refresh on the source object, not the layer.

Answer (score 6):

You should call `redraw()` method on layer not map - `this.vector.redraw()`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that too, and it didn't work (although I think it should!)

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could also try to call refresh() method on layer. I would also try calling deactivate() method on strategy instead of setting high treshhold - this.vector.strategies[0].deactivate(). You can also try to listen to map's "movestart" instead of "zoomend". I think features are not drawn yet on movestart so you have better chance to prevent things from happening.

Answer (score 5):

For openlayers > 3

```
vectorlayer.getSource().refresh()
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the earlier answers worked for me. I read Open Layers 3 API and found [ol.layer.Vector.changed()](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html#changed), which helped me. Use like: `vectorLayer.changed()`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem thanks to this file: CenteredCluster.js, that i include after `<script src="... /OpenLayers.js"></script>` . I catch the file from this example: http://jorix.github.io/OL-Ragbag/examples/sundials.html for reference: https://github.com/jorix/OL-Ragbag

Then i don'`t use cluster strategy method, but the class of the file, CenteredCluster that you can set with ZoomRange options to control the behaviour of the clusters (activation, deactivation, distance and treshold):

```
   var centeredCluster = new OpenLayers.Strategy.CenteredCluster({
zoomSettings: [
    {zoomRange: [0, 2], settings: {distance: 10}},
    {zoomRange: [3, 4], settings: {distance: 10}},
    // 5 normal clusters
    {zoomRange: [6, 14], settings: {threshold: 2}},
    {zoomRange: [15, 99], settings: {enabled: false}}
]
});

 var urlKMLClient = 'features.kml'; 
 var layerKMLClient = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Clients", {
      style : style,

     strategies: [centeredCluster, new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: urlKMLClient,
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true, 
            extractAttributes: true,
            maxDepth: 2
        })
    })
}
);
     map.addLayer(layerKMLClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

In OL3 refresh it by calling layer's source refresh() method

`layer.getSource().refresh()`

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue just use
 `map.updateSize();`

Comment: Can you please explain where and how to use it and why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `OL` 3.10.1 I do:

```
WMSLayer.getSource().updateParams({"time": Date.now()});
WFSLayer.clear();
```

Both layers (`WMS` and `WFS`) are refreshed successfully.

There are so many different information regarding this functionality in `OL` and the biggest problem is that nobody defines an `OL` version on which something works :)

Hopefully this will help someone!