# drag one feature from cluster in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

How to drag cluster in a layer ? After dragging a particular feature from a cluster i want to remove that feature from cluster.

```
var strategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({distance:10,threshold:2});
poiLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("poiLayer",{strategies:[strategy],styleMap:stylemap});
map.addLayer(poiLayer); 
strategy.activate();
drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(poiLayer);
map.addControl(drag);
drag.activate();
```

Is it possible to drag individual feature from cluster?

Comment: I tried reclustering for strategy . But individual feature drag is not happening . Any urgent help is appreciated

Comment: any help? I tried every possible ways

Comment: This answer will help you [OpenLayers Cluster Recalculate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457437/openlayers-cluster-recalculate)